# shapefile driver table name mismatch for ogr vs. shp2pgsql

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr, shp2pgsql

I have a shapefile which if I convert to sql statements using shp2pgsql 
 return table name all in lowercase, for e.g. 'liberia'.

When I read the same shapefile using ogr and use layer.GetName() it returns
capitalized name e.g. 'Liberia'.

Is the  mismatch because I am not looking at the right variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shp2pgsql converts all table and field names to lower case because Postgres prefers lower case table and field names, you have to put field names in quotes when you write queries with field names that have upper or mixed case names.

If you want to keep these identifiers uppercase use the "-k" switch in shp2pgsql.

http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive

Comment: ogr2ogr also support setting output layer name via -nln key. Also you can provide some layer creation options via -lco parameter (supported values see here: http://gdal.org/drv_pg.html)